# How to add a webview to the View in Appgyver

Tags: javascript, angularjs, steroids

I have created a Controller and I intend to load a website in a WebView.

Controller:

```
angular
  .module('example')
  .controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic) {
      $scope.navbarTitle = "Index";
      alert("Starting");      
  });
```

View:

```
<div class="padding" ng-controller="IndexController">
    <super-navbar>
        <super-navbar-title>
            Hello!
        </super-navbar-title>
    </super-navbar>
    <super-navigate view-id="using-the-scanner">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive icon-left super-wand">Using the AppGyver Scanner</button>
    </super-navigate>
    <super-navigate view-id="learn-more">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive icon-left super-university">Learn more</button>
    </super-navigate>    
</div>
```

I only found JS code:

```
var googleLayer = new steroids.views.WebView("http://www.google.com");
```

How can I add that to the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are ready then just call
`steroids.layers.push(googleLayer);`

Comment: I used _steroid.layers.replace_ but essentially it is the same operation.